# JMH benchmarking results difference when using OperationsPerInvocation

Tags: java, jmh

I simply wanted to benchmark Java ArrayList add() method, I wrote my own percentile producer bechmark class and compared it with what JMH produces. I was surprised to see if I add 100M entries to an ArrayList using a loop inside a @Benchmark using OperationPerInvocation, I get very different result from if I execute one add operation per benchmark without loop. For example:

```
@Benchmark
public void addItems(ThreadState state, Blackhole blackhole) {
    blackhole.consume(addItems(state.list, state.items, state.value));
}

private static boolean addItems(List<Long> list, int items, long value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < items; i++) {
        list.add(value);
    }
    return true;
}
```

shows 99.99 percentile of about 0.030us whereas with the following code (setting measurement time to about 9 seconds) it comes to 0.80us.

```
@Benchmark
public void add(ListState listState, Blackhole blackhole) {
    listState.list.add(listState.val);
}
```

Is it because calling one add operation per benchmark comes with a lot of "overhead" of calling it, at least the debugger shows it. Whereas executing add() method inside a loop doesn't have that much JMH code in between?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this method

```java
private static boolean addItems(List<Long> list, int items, long value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < items; i++) {
        list.add(value);
    }
    return true;
}
```

always returns a constant value independent on execution of the loop and might get constant folded so I'd rewrite the code like

```java
private static boolean addItems(List<Long> list, int items, long value) {
    boolean value = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < items; i++) {
        value &= list.add(value);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Second,

> Whereas executing add() method inside a loop doesn't have that much JMH code in between?

There's no JMH code within the loop with `add()` method at all, if you'd go down through the stack trace you'd see that your `@Benchmark`-annotated method is called from JMH-generated stub that does the measurements and collects the results. In your first example all the loop is measured as an atomic piece of workload. On the contrary in the second case each invocation of `add()` is measured atomically along with the costs of reading fields `listState.list` and `listState.val` from `ListState` object. In the first example you read them only once per loop, in the second - as many times as the benchmark method is called.

Third, there's no interaction with the Blackhole in the second case,  I guess it should be either

```java
@Benchmark
public void add(ListState listState, Blackhole blackhole) {
    blackhole.consume(listState.list.add(listState.val));
}
```

or

```java
@Benchmark
public boolean add(ListState listState) {
    return listState.list.add(listState.val);
}
```

Comment: 1st point  - though “true” is hardcoded/constant folded, a value in the list is always added, I verified values added inside the list after a benchmark run, so compiler is not removing it. On second point - when I say JMH code, I meant JMH handing over work to threads which may trigger context switching? Compare to using a loop inside a benchmark, this approach would certainly have some JMH overhead.

Comment: I like your point about state.list and state.value being read millions of times in the non-loop case. I’ll give that a try, but I thought pointer to list will be cached so memory shouldn’t be accessed millions of times.

Comment: "pointer to list will be cached so memory shouldn’t be accessed millions of times." I doubt, as the `state` is injected into the method by JMH's infrastructure.

Comment: Didn't make any difference, infact i removed adding removing from the list all together,  just a simple benchmark producing random integers swallowed by a blackhole. The one inside loop is way faster. I noticed JMH calls the benchmark via the method handler and waits for it to finish via Future. It seems as JMH benchmark execution overhead is the cause of the delay.

Comment: Yeah, probably you are right, it's about the infrastructure of JMH.